# Possible to run WebGL content from an android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, webgl, virtualbox, bluestacks

Hello I have been trying to run WebGL content in a number of android emulators( BlueStacks, Andy, Duos, and VirtualBox ). When I try to access any WebGL content in a browser( chrome, firefox ) I get a message stating that WebGL is not supported by my video card. Of course WebGL works fine outside of the emulator. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this blog post: http://blog.tojicode.com/2013/11/the-state-of-webgl-on-chrome-aka-why.html

It might be that all of the emulators don't support the OpenGL Extension

```
 GL_EXT_robustness
```

Comment: Read the blog post. The author mentions both black listing devices and possible force flag for Chrome for Android. Honestly if you are testing something as resource intensive as WebGL you probably should be using a device.