# how to implement webgl rendering in android webview

Tags: android, webgl

I have created a javascript 3d game using three.js. Now i want to convert that to android apk. But unfortunately android's webview is not supporting WebGL. Is there anyway to convert that to apk

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) to port your javascript game to mobile platforms. Check it out!

Using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) you need to install cordova globally first by:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Once the installation finishes, you can create a project by:

```
cordova create mygame
```

Then you can `cd mygame` to the directory and add platforms to your project.

```
cordova platform add android
```

Put your game code in the index.html file and to run the game execute:

```
cordova run android
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16861873)

Comment: Edited the answer to provide information about how to setup an android cordova project.

Answer (score 1):

WebGL should be supported in Android 5.0 and up.

[Enabling WebGL support for Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395245/enabling-webgl-support-for-android-webview)

Perhaps you are trying on a emulator which doesn't have WebGL support:

[Possible to run WebGL content from an android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789443/possible-to-run-webgl-content-from-an-android-emulator/32789972#32789972)